# Custom Task Pane Office(Excel) many times slide to open on Excel 2013

Tags: c#, excel-2013, customtaskpane

I created my own Excel Addin and after clicking the button displays a Custom Task Pane on right. Everything is fine but when I run this addin in Excel 2013. This displays Custom Task Panes with slide it open.For my Addin Flashes disappear and appear. It looks like a problem with the display.
Is there any solution? It looks very, very wrong.

PS. I'm sure they do not Set Custom Task Panes instance twice.

Display and hide performed using xxxxxxx.Visible = true / false;

Slide to close is Ok.

-------ThisAddIn.cs

_calcTaskPaneControl = new UI.CalcTaskPane();
_calcTaskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(_calcTaskPaneControl, Common.CommonFunctions.GetLocalizeText("ThisAddIn_CalcTaskPaneTitle"));
_calcTaskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(CalcTaskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);

--------MainRibbon.cs

Globals.ThisAddIn.CalcTaskPane.Visible = true;

Comment: Can you please post some code, it is not easy to interpret what is going on from your question

Comment: Im not shore if code help. Then I create simple CustomTaskPane. And show them (change visible to true). Then in Excel 2013 start animation like taskPane incoming from left. BUT animation is very fast show then go back to hide and create god animation - > slide taskPane from left.

Comment: Is look like i show them hide them and show. But I dont do this ... eny idea? Any sugestion or is freeky bug?

Comment: I am experience exactly the same issue, have you found the solution to that problem? thx

Comment: Unfortunately not, everything I tried to suggest that this is a bug. It's been a while but we have found nothing that would permanently functional work. Sorry, but if you finde something, please post it.

Comment: Same thing happening for customtaskpane in Outlook 2013 also? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the same with Excel 2013. Whenever you set the visibility or the width, Excel 2013 reloads the taskpane. I had to updated all places to check if the CustomTaskPane not already is visible or invisible before setting it. So when your CTP is visible and you set Visible to True again, it will reload the taskpane. Excel 2010 doesn't do this.